# How to read this syntax?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and solving a problem from a coding website, which has input such as,

```
[1, Node { data: 2, next: Node { data: 3, next: null } } ]
```

This is clearly a linked list and I want to parse the data but I couldn't understand the syntax. Could you please tell me, what `Node{...}` syntax means here ?

Comment: The second value in the parent array is an javascript object which has in turn second object at "next" keyword which has two properties data with 3as value and next with null as value

Comment: You can't understand it because it's invalid syntax throwing an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` exception  - I didn't DV btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste this code to a JS interpreter, it cannot execute it. It's no valid JS code, but a stringified output of a JS datastructure.
I guess `Node` is an object, which contains a `data` attribute, and a `next` attribute.

Thus this is the custom console representation of

```
class Node {
  constructor(data, next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

const list = [1, new Node(2, new Node(3, null))];

console.log(list); // should be similar to [1, Node { data: 2, next: Node { data: 3, next: null } } ]
```